# SQL Join With Two Tables and Retrieve data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table 1 - DEFECT

```
Defect ID | Name             | Type
--------------------------------
SB001     | Light Bead       | Bead
SB002     | Narrow Bead      | Bead
SB003     | ROUND BEAD       | Bead
SB004     | O`RING LEAK      | Bead
C0001     | Spread cord      | GT
C0002     | Sidewall wrinkle | GT
```

Table 2 - Tyres Defect

```
Tyre S/N   | DEFECT ID | Datetime
------------------------------
0108160020 | SB004     | 2019-01-09 21:43:01.293
2512160005 | SB003     | 2019-01-10 00:05:29.150
3010160003 | SB004     | 2019-01-11 00:05:29.150
```

I need Result like Below

```
Defect ID  | Defect Name | Type
------------------------
SB004      | O`RING LEAK | BEAD
SB003      | ROUND BEAD  | BEAD
SB001      | Light Bead  | BEAD
SB002      | Narrow Bead | BEAD
```

I want to get first the defects who getting Frequently and other defects are
order by name or something

thanks help me....

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by 'frequently' and 'other defects'; are you asking for defects in descending order of frequency of occurrence.

Comment: **First:** what have you tried? **Second:** Is there any particular reason that exclude `C0001` and `C0002` from your expected result since you wrote: _get first the defects who getting Frequently and **other defects are order by name or something**_

Comment: Is this `MySQL` or `sql-server` - different products, differences in syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    DF.[Defect ID],
    DF.[Name],
    DF.[Type],
    COUNT(DF.*) AS [Defect count]
FROM
    DEFECT AS DF
    LEFT JOIN
    [Tyres Defect] AS TD
    ON DF.[Defect ID] = TD.[Defect ID]
GROUP BY
    DF.[Defect ID],
    [Name],
    [Type]
ORDER BY
    COUNT(DF.[Defect ID]) DESC
    DF.[Name]
```

Which will also give you a count of each defect type. (This is the answer for `sql-server`